# handshake in ssl connect from javascript

Tags: java, ssl, websocket, handshake

how i can to make handshake in ssl connect in java?

when i connected without ssl i used this code

```
    InputStream in = client.getInputStream();

    OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();

    //translate bytes of request to string
     data = new Scanner(in,"UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\r\\n\\r\\n").next();

    System.out.println("data="+data);


    Matcher get = Pattern.compile("^GET").matcher(data);

    if (get.find()) {
        Matcher match = Pattern.compile("Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)").matcher(data);
        match.find();
        try {
        byte[] response = ("HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n"
                + "Connection: Upgrade\r\n"
                + "Upgrade: websocket\r\n"
                + "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: "
                + DatatypeConverter
                .printBase64Binary(
                        MessageDigest
                        .getInstance("SHA-1")
                        .digest((match.group(1) + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11")
                                .getBytes("UTF-8")))
                + "\r\n\r\n")
                .getBytes("UTF-8");

        out.write(response, 0, response.length);

        System.out.println("-----response1----- "+"HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n"+ "Connection: Upgrade\r\n"+ "Upgrade: websocket\r\n"
                    + "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: "+ DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1").digest((match.group(1) + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11").getBytes("UTF-8")))+ "\r\n\r\n");


        }

    }
```

how i can make handshake in next code?

```
        SSLServerSocketFactory sslserversocketfactory =
                (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
        SSLServerSocket sslserversocket =
                (SSLServerSocket) sslserversocketfactory.createServerSocket(9999);
                System.out.println("Server has started on 127.0.0.1:80.\r\nWaiting for a connection...");
        SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslserversocket.accept();
        InputStream inputstream = sslsocket.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
         InputStream in = sslsocket.getInputStream();
OutputStream out = sslsocket.getOutputStream();



        BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);
        System.out.println("5");
        String string = null;
        while ((string = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("6");
            System.out.println(string);
            System.out.flush();
        }
```

without handshake  i've got error

index.js:1 WebSocket connection to 'wss://127.0.0.1:9999/' failed: WebSocket opening handshake was canceled